# Is there any way to update my mapbox gl source?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, mapbox, render

Hello i have a problem when i try to update my mapbox source on click.

I have already to sources (cells , heatmap), I try to add a new sources with these code

```
 this.map.addSource("points", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [-77.0323, 38.9131],
          },
          properties: {
            title: "Mapbox DC",
            "marker-symbol": "monument",
          },
        },
      });
```

I also try delele sources (cells , heatmap), add then a dd a new sources.

this.map.removeLayer("heatmap");
this.map.removeSource("heatmap");

```
  this.map.removeLayer("cells");
  this.map.removeSource("cells");

  this.map.addSource("points", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [-77.0323, 38.9131],
      },
      properties: {
        title: "Mapbox DC",
        "marker-symbol": "monument",
      },
    },
  });
```

I don't get any error in the browser console from mapbox but i cant see the new sources.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution i have wrong coordinates ( i have lat,lot but we want lot,lat) –